# Application as global variable

Tags: java, android

i searched for way to store a global variables that will be shared with all the activities.

i found this:

[How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

and i created a class that extends application and i declare this application in the manifest file.

however i have a problem:

i cant decalre more than one application in the manifest file...

therefore if i want to declare two applications, what can i do?

here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sa"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>



    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <permission
    android:name="com.example.sa.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />



    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.sa.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>




    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
         android:debuggable="true"
        android:name=".FriendPickerApplication">



        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sa.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


              </activity>

         <!--  Entry for RegisterActivity.class -->
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
                  android:label="Register New Account"></activity>
        <meta-data android:value="@string/app_id" android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"/>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" android:label="Profile page"></activity>

        <meta-data
              android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
              android:value="xxxx"/>


        <activity android:name="DashBoardActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="AllItemsActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="itemCategory"></activity>
        <activity android:name="ItemMapActivity"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and i also want to delare a class that extends application that will store the shared variables:

```
<application android:name="MyApp" 
   android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
   android:label="@string/app_name2"></application>
```

and this is the class:

```
class MyApp extends Application {

  private String myState;

  public String getState(){
    return myState;
  }
  public void setState(String s){
    myState = s;
  }
}

class Blah extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    ...
    MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
    String state = appState.getState();
    ...
  }
}
```

thanks alot

Comment: Why not have several variables: ie myState1 and myState2, and get one or the other?

Comment: i need to pass alot of variables each time between activities, i want to declare them to be global and shared between all activities..

Comment: Why do you need two separate applications? Why can't you have multiple activities all contained inside a single application?

Comment: i read that i can use this application as a global variable, is there another way to implement a global variable which will be shared between all activities?

Answer (score 1):

You can not declare more than one application.

You can have more variables in you application, but application is a singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

To define Global Variable you can make use of static Keyword:

```
public static String myState;
```

Comment: hi, in which activity do i declare this variable? thanks alot

Comment: @AdirRahamim Declare global variable as I mentioned above.

Comment: where do i need to declare this variable? i dont understand that

Comment: @AdirRahamim In MyApp class.

Comment: however i cant declare myApp because i have allready another aplication in the manifest file (the facebook application) ..therefore i cant declare myApp..